# Show comment number per author per day

Tags: posts, author, comments

Is this possible? I've never seen it used, but I need it... I want to show for each author (if they are logged in) on their own profile page, the amount of comments they have posted today. If the day passes by, than the counter has to be 0 and the comment counter has to start again.

Comment: Based on the previous answers to your questions you should already be able to write such a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query that counts user comments by using the `user_id` field in the comments table as a filter:

```
function count_user_comments_today( $uid ){
    global $wpdb;
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $tomorrow = date('Y-m-d', time() + 86400);
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->comments} WHERE user_id = %d  AND comment_date >= %s  AND comment_date < %s ", $uid, $today, $tomorrow  ));
    return $count;
}
```

where we use PHP to give the current date and we don't use any SQL date functions on each row.

You could also consider using the [WP_Comment_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) class if you are looking for a more  native solution.

### Usage:

You can use it like this for the current logged in user:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo count_user_comments_today( $current_user->ID );
```

and for the current author:

```
echo count_user_comments_today( get_the_author_meta('ID') );
```

in the loop in the template page `author.php`.

Outside the loop in `author.php` you can use:

```
global $wp_query;
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
echo count_user_comments_today( $curauth->ID );
```

for the current author.

Comment: We are close... The problem with this is that it gets the LOGGED IN users comments. If I go to an author profile, I want for each author the comment amount per day. Now it shows the logged in users comment number, which is the same on all author pages. Can you solve that?

Comment: ok, please try the updated answer.

Comment: Nope, did not work either. It shows a zero for an author, even if I post messages.

Comment: I guess you are then outside the loop in `author.php`, please try it inside the loop. The function `get_the_author_meta('ID')` works for me in for example the TwentyTwelve theme after the `the_post()` call in `author.php`.

Comment: I added an usage example when you are outside the loop also.

Comment: That was the problem indeed. Very much appreciated, thank you birgire, I owe you one!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's definitely possible.  Refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment, you'll need to get the current server time in UNIX format and then convert `comment_date_gmt` from each returned be using a `foreach` loop

```
function current_user_comments_today() {
 global $comment;
 global $current_user;
 get_currentuserinfo();
 $all_user_comments = get_comments( array( 'comment_author_email' => $current_user-> user_email) );
 $today = strtotime('today GMT'); 
 $tomorrow = strtotime('today +1 GMT'); 
 $comment_count = 0;
 foreach ( $all_user_comments as $key => $comment ) {
    $comment_time = strtotime( $comment['comment_date_gmt'] );
    if ( $comment_time > $tomorrow && $comment_time < $today ) {
      $comment_count++;
    } else {
      continue;
    }
 }
 return $comment_count; 
}
```

Comment: Obviously this is going to be quite slow so any suggestions to limit the query scope are welcome, but I don't think `get_comments()` is very friendly to a scope limit by time... could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to directly pull this query with Core functions, but the SQL is simple.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) 
        FROM {$wpdb->comments} 
        WHERE comment_author = 'admin' 
        AND DATE(comment_date) = FROM_UNIXTIME('".time()."')";
$a = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
```

You can alternately use something like `AND DATE(comment_date) = FROM_UNIXTIME('".time()."')";` to pick out any particular date.